# How to work with silverlight 3.0 with visual studio 2008?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend, wpftoolkit

How to work with silverlight 3.0 with visual studio 2008?

Which version or service packs of visual studio should be installed to work with silverlight?

I installed silverlight toolkit july 2009 release but controls are not visible in visual studio 2008 RTM i.e. installed in my PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott Guthrie has a good rundown of what you need here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/10/silverlight-3-released.aspx

In short, the only thing you really need is the [Microsoft Silverlight 3 Tools for Visual Studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9442b0f2-7465-417a-88f3-5e7b5409e9dd&displaylang=en) but you might also get benefit from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24246) which contains a bunch of additional controls. In terms of Visualo Studio, make sure you have SP1 installed first.